# Dropdown based on user input

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Guys could someone help me to find solution for following case:

I have to type several letters for username (actually typed whole username) and click on it to choose. It looks as on screenshot which I added below.

Here is how it looks like on a page:

```
Added part
<div class="show-temp">
<div class="medium-12 column">
<div id="suggestionBox" class="search-input">
<label for="viewUser">Search user names</label>

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="viewUser" onkeydown="javascript: if(event.keyCode == 13 ){ userStats.HideContent();userStats.ApplyFilters(this); return false;}" placeholder="Search user names..">
```

I tried with this code:

```
Select dropdown2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"viewUser\"]")));
    dropdown2.selectByVisibleText("Zoran21");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

And I got this error:

```
Element should have been "select" but was "input"
```

Please assist and thank you in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please paste few more lines of your html code

Comment: I guess it should be something with ul tag

Comment: @AaryaHareendranath added below 'Added part' four lines of html which are above filter

Comment: That 4 lines doesn't help.

Comment: @AaryaHareendranath added screenshot of html page, Hope this will help

Comment: Is there way to get whole code , I am unable to understand from where this dropdown starts if there are more than one matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Select class** only works with `<select>` tags ,it's does not work for other Tags LIke (`Input,div`).if you want to work with DropDown first check the `DoM` ,how it's build .if its contain `<select>` Tag then Use  `Select Class` other wise following the Below Approach.

The Error Indicates to you , DropDown  Build With `<Input>` Tag so Your unable to Select Options By using  **Select Class**

**use below approach may be it's help you.**

```
String searchUserXpath ="....";
String optionXpath ="----"
driver.findElement(By.xpath(searchUserXpath )).sendKeys(entersearchOptionValue totally /partially );
//for example option value is HYderabad ,you HYd Then takes xpath of 
 //  HyderabaOPtion...
driver.findElement(By.xpath(optionXpath )).click();
```